# Feeds tamper find and replace

Tags: commerce, feeds

Is it possible with Feeds Tamper to find something in a string and replace all the string with something ?

```
Ex : I've got a .csv file and column 23 can contain something like:
"XL SSR FR RB" or "XL TL RB"
```

I need to find if this column contains SSR, and rewrite everyting to 1 or 0

```
Ex : "XL SSR FR RB"  => "1"
     "XL TL RB"      => "0"
```

Is this something the tamper module can do ?

If it's possible to convert it to boolean it's even better.

Thanks.

Comment: There's a reg ex plugin in Feeds Tamper. Can you write a reg ex to count occurrences of SSR?

Comment: I don't know anything about reg ex, but I will try to take a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you'll need two tampers for that field. [From the manual:](https://www.drupal.org/node/1246578)

1. **Find replace REGEX**
   Find and replace a user-specified string using REGEX with an option to limit the number of replacements. See the PHP Manual on PCRE Pattern Syntax for a complete reference, or RegexPal for a quick tester.
2. **Convert to boolean**
   Convert a user-specified string to boolean, with the option of specifying what to do in the case of no match.

Here is a regular expression that will find `SSR` and replace the entire string with it.

https://regex101.com/r/aO0uG3/2

`/\b(SSR)\b/\1/`

Then match `SSR` in the Convert to boolean tamper. (**Note:** The regex in the screen shot is now out of date. Use `/\b/(SSR)\b/` instead)

[image: Configure Find replace REGEX]
[image: Configure Convert to boolean]
[image: Final result]

Comment: Hey ! Thank you for your answer and for the regex ! Since I didn't tell you everything, I have another request, is it possible with this regex code to do the same with multiple characters ( Ex. find SSR => rewrite everything / find RF => rewrite everything  / find RAF => rewrite... so on... ) ? EDIT : oh and this regex doesn't match if SSR if on the begening.

Comment: I think you can add the same source field again and map it to another Content type field with its own rewrite. Would that work? Are the destination fields for SSR and RF, RAF &c. different? Matching the SSR at the beginning (or end) of the string would require removing the `.+` at the start (and end) of the REGEX which would then match SSSR and SSRR. I will look to see if there is a better way to find the edges of the match.

Comment: Ok I've updated the regex and the link to use `\b` (word boundary) instead. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6713310/how-to-specify-space-or-end-of-string-and-space-or-start-of-string

Answer (score 0):

[image]**Step 1.** Install the Feed Tamper php module and enabled it.
https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper_php

**Step 2.** Now select the Excute php code option from add plugin regarding the required.

**Step 3.** Paste the following code there...

```
    //$field contains the value whatever value you are passing by required column

    $required_column_value = $field;
    $find_str = "SSR";

    $pos = strpos($required_column_value, $find_str);
    if($pos){
       return 1;// now $field value would be 1
    }else{
       return 0;// now $field value would be 0
    }
```

**NOTE :: Here don't confuse due to field name username in screen shot it would be your required field name.**